# Join Multiple Tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to JOIN these tables:

[image: Tables in MySQL Workbench]

The query I am trying to build is Consultants assigned to Patients, to get the consultants names, the JOIN is needed onto Staff and Consultant based on the Staff ID (STA_id). Then join to Consultant onto Patient based on the Consultant ID (CON_id).

Here is what I generated so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Patient.PAT_f_name,' ',Patient.PAT_l_name) AS Patient_Name, 
       CONCAT(Staff.STA_f_name,' ',Staff.STA_s_name) AS Consultant_Name
FROM up637415_hospital.Patient
JOIN up637415_hospital.Consultant ON 
     up637415_hospital.Patient.CON_id=up637415_hospital.Consultant.CON_id
JOIN up637415_hospital.Staff ON 
     up637415_hospital.Consultant.STA_id=up637415_hospital.Consultant.STA_id
```

The query outputs these results:
[image: Results of Query]

It is repeating the Patients names.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As an aside, you probably don't need to include the database name in the query

Comment: _“It is repeating the Patients names”_ – well what else do you expect if there’s multiple consultants assigned to a patient?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the last line of the query. If you used table aliases, this kind of problem would be easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this solution by using the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Patient.PAT_f_name,' ',Patient.PAT_l_name) AS Patient_Name, 
CONCAT(Staff.STA_f_name,' ',Staff.STA_s_name) AS Consultant_Name
    FROM up637415_hospital.Patient
JOIN up637415_hospital.Consultant ON 
     up637415_hospital.Patient.CON_id=up637415_hospital.Consultant.CON_id
JOIN up637415_hospital.Staff ON 
     up637415_hospital.Consultant.STA_id=up637415_hospital.Consultant.STA_id
WHERE Staff.STA_id=Consultant.STA_id AND Consultant.CON_id=Patient.CON_id
```

I just needed to use a where clause.